# Spring Boot + OpenAPI + Oauth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth2, swagger, openapi

Tengo el backend de una aplicación y me han encargado generar la documentación usando OpenAPI. Por fin lo tengo y he habilitado el botón "Authorize", que permite pegar un JWT.

Me gustaría ir un poco más allá y que, en lugar de pegar el JWT se pudiera introducir un usuario y contraseña que se envían al login de nuestro servicio de Oauth y que, a partir de ahí se usara el JWT que se recibe para autenticar las llamadas.

¿Esto es posible? He visto algo parecido en Swagger, pero implica editar cosas como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no sé dónde está eso en OpenAPI, puesto que es "autogenerado"

Comment: ya intentaste con la dependencia springfox-swagger-ui?

Comment: No, no lo he intentado con esa, solo con "springdoc-openapi-ui". Si lo intento con la que me dices, la documentación también se autogenera? Qué ventajas tiene springfox sobre openAPI o viceversa? Gracias!

Comment: tambien, la diferencia intuyo yo es que no se genera como un archivo, sino que te da dos endpoints, uno para el json del Open API specification y el otro la interfaz interactiva para llamarlo